# PostgreSQL: simple equality query returning no results for indexed columns

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-9.5, csv

I have a very large table (around 140M rows) with five columns:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS citations 
(
   citing_id text,
   citing_issn text,
   cited_id text,
   cited_issn text,
   year int
);
```

There are hash indexes on `citing_id` and on `cited_id`, neither of which has any NULL values (confirmed), but queries selecting on equality in these columns are returning zero results no matter what. Even this query, which I would think would work in any populated table, returns zero rows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM citations 
WHERE citing_id IN (SELECT citing_id 
                    FROM citations LIMIT 1) 
LIMIT 100;
```

However, the same query on a *non*-indexed column works exactly as expected:

```
SELECT * 
FROM citations 
WHERE citing_issn IN (SELECT citing_issn 
                      FROM citations LIMIT 1) 
LIMIT 100;
```

The data was loaded from a CSV file using the `COPY` command, and I suspect there may be extra hidden characters on the end of the indexed values -- querying with `WHERE citing_id LIKE '<id>%'` is very slow (hash indexes don't help with partial strings) but returns the right results. Still, the first query above should work no matter what, unless I'm mistaken.

I'm running Postgres 9.5.3.0 on MacOS 10.13.1

**edit**:

The query plan for the first query (on the indexed column, returning no rows) is:

```
Limit  (cost=0.03..1.38 rows=100 width=58)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.03..265.83 rows=19751 width=58)
         ->  HashAggregate  (cost=0.03..0.04 rows=1 width=17)
               Group Key: citations_1.citing_id
               ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=17)
                     ->  Seq Scan on citations citations_1  (cost=0.00..3164425.68 rows=148131768 width=17)
         ->  Index Scan using citations_citing_id on citations  (cost=0.00..265.14 rows=65 width=58)
               Index Cond: (citing_id = citations_1.citing_id)
```

and for the second query (on the non-indexed column, returning expected results):

```
Limit  (cost=0.04..139.54 rows=100 width=58)
   ->  Hash Semi Join  (cost=0.04..3581836.35 rows=2567617 width=58)
         Hash Cond: (citations.citing_issn = citations_1.citing_issn)
         ->  Seq Scan on citations  (cost=0.00..3164425.68 rows=148131768 width=58)
         ->  Hash  (cost=0.03..0.03 rows=1 width=10)
               ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=10)
                     ->  Seq Scan on citations citations_1  (cost=0.00..3164425.68 rows=148131768 width=10)
```

Comment: What says that `SELECT citing_id FROM citations LIMIT 1` cannot return NULL ?

Comment: What happens if you remove those indexes? What are the execution plans for both statements? Did you verify if there are any trailing blanks in the values?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. `SELECT citing_id FROM citations LIMIT 1` returns exactly one row with a non-NULL value. There are no NULL values in the table.

Comment: There is trailing whitespace in the indexed values. Will that break the index or `WHERE` clause?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name :
I dropped the hash index on `cited_id`, and now a query on that column works. It looks like it was the index specifically that was preventing the query from matching.

Comment: Peter, what does this return?: `SELECT COUNT(*), COUNT(citing_id) FROM citations;` Even one row with `NULL` in `citing_id` can make  your first query return 0 rows.

Comment: This query however will always return at least 1 row from the table - unless the table has no rows: `SELECT * 
FROM citations 
WHERE citing_id IS NOT DISTINCT FROM (SELECT citing_id FROM citations LIMIT 1) ;`

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ `SELECT COUNT(*), COUNT(citing_id) FROM citations;` gives me `148130999 | 148130999`, and your second query (`NOT DISTINCT FROM`) gives me the 29 rows I would expect. Is it true that if there are no NULLs in a column, the query from my question should return at least 1 row? It seems like it is only queries that are using the hash index that are returning nothing.

Answer (score 2):

> There are hash indexes on citing_id and on cited_id, neither of which
>   has any NULL values (confirmed), but queries selecting on equality in
>   these columns are returning zero results no matter what.

The index is probably **corrupted**. Hash indexes are only WAL-logged since PostgreSQL 10. In previous versions, they don't have that mechanism that makes them persist correctly across unclean shutdowns.

The doc on [CREATE INDEX for 9.5](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createindex.html) has this warning:

> Hash index operations are not presently WAL-logged, so hash indexes
>   might need to be rebuilt with REINDEX after a database crash if there
>   were unwritten changes. Also, changes to hash indexes are not
>   replicated over streaming or file-based replication after the initial
>   base backup, so they give wrong answers to queries that subsequently
>   use them. Hash indexes are also not properly restored during
>   point-in-time recovery. For these reasons, hash index use is presently
>   discouraged.

Consider upgrading to PostgreSQL 10, and in the meantime, `REINDEX` the hash indexes.